# Merge two multidimensional arrays into one in Php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I have two multidimensional arrays in PhP and I am trying to create a new array which is flatter.

The first array is called weeksBooked and has a structure like below:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [periodweekno] => 27
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [periodweekno] => 28
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [periodweekno] => 29
    )
)
```

The second one is called bookings . This stores the day a child was booked for that particular week.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [periodDayName] => Monday
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [periodDayName] => Tuesday
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [periodDayName] => Thursday
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [periodDayName] => Friday
    )

)
```

I am trying to merge both the arrays and check if the perioddayName is Monday then in the "new" merged array I can show it as "monday"=> 0 and if not  then show it as "monday"=> 1.  I would like to repeat it for each "workday (i.e. monday - friday).

I apologise in advance if I am not explaining it well but this is what I am trying to achieve is a structure that I can bind to a table:

```
{Weekno:27, Monday:1,Tuesday:0,Wednedsay:1,Thursday:1,Friday:0
Weekno:28, Monday:0,Tuesday:0,Wednesday:1, Thursday:0,Friday:1}
```

This is my attempt so far but I just can't get it to flatten it :

```
 $result = array();
 foreach ($weeksbooked as $week) {

       $sql = "SELECT periodDayName FROM Attendance WHERE weekno = ". $week['periodweekno'];

        $bookings = $this->db->RawQuery($sql,null);
       // print_r($bookings);

        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {

            $daysbooked= array();

            if($booking['periodDayName'] == 'Monday'){
                $daysbooked['monday'] = 0;
            }else{
                $daysbooked['monday'] = 1;
            }
             if($booking['periodDayName'] == 'Tuesday'){
                $daysbooked['tuesday'] = 0;
            }else{
                $daysbooked['tuesday'] = 1;
            }
       .....
     array_push($weeksbooked,$daysbooked)
   }

array_push($result,$weekbooked)
```

Comment: A couple of things: 1) you have a `$weeks['weekno']` variable that you set but then don't use it (maybe you just didn't include that part of the code), 2) watch your sentence case!  You declare $weeksbooked and $daysbooked but then later are using $weeksBooked and $daysBooked... different variables!  3) what do you mean by "flattening it"... do you want the result in an array structure, or a collection of strings?

Comment: Thank you @FoulFoot I have edited the question and have taken care of the issues you  raised.

Comment: You posted code and the code in the accepted answer are making iterated calls to the database -- this is poor practice.  If you can create a sql fiddle of the relevant tables, Nick or I will surely be able to help you to craft a more elegant and efficient single-query solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
$result = array();
foreach ($weeksbooked as $week) {
    $sql = "SELECT periodDayName FROM Attendance WHERE weekno = ". $week['periodweekno']; 
    $bookings = $this->db->RawQuery($sql,null);
    // print_r($bookings);  
    $thisweek = array('Weekno' => $week['periodweekno'], 
                      'Monday' => 0,
                      'Tuesday' => 0,
                      'Wednesday' => 0,
                      'Thursday' => 0,
                      'Friday' => 0
                      );
    foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
        $thisweek[$booking['periodDayName']] = 1;
    }
    $result[] = $thisweek;
}
print_r($result);
```

It should produce an output something like what you are looking for. Without the raw data in a table it's hard to be certain.

Comment: Good answer.   How to get a static weeks

Comment: @Muthusamy thanks. Not sure what you mean by your comment?

Comment: @Nick Thank you it worked perfectly!! I think  Muthusamy is asking is how to get all the weeks. I have them stored in a table (bit slow) but have constraints  from the framework I have to use.

Comment: @Nick iterated queries are not great.  I hope the OP will offer the necessary details so that a solution with best practices can be provided.